# OBIEE 12.2.1.0.0 - Fully control sort order of a chart

Tags: charts, obiee

Is it possible to control the sort order of all the elements of a chart?

The specific case I have is that of a 100% stacked bar chart of a sales table with ProductName, NumSales, CustomerAge and CustomerAgeGroup, where this last attribute is defined with a CASE over CustomerAge so each customer has 'Child', 'Teenager', 'Adult' or 'Pensionist' as CustomerAgeGroup.

In the chart each bar is a product (ProductName) and the bar is coloured showing the distribution of CustomerAgeGroup of the buyers of each product. Right now, the chart reads something like this:

- **Action Man:** 'Teenager' (10%), 'Pensionist' (25%), 'Child' (5%), 'Adult' (60%)
- **Matrix:** 'Teenager' (20%), 'Pensionist' (10%), 'Child' (5%), 'Adult' (65%)

I am not worried about the order of ProductName, but notice the descending order of CustomerAgeGroup: is it possible to display CustomerAgeGroup sorted by the order of CustomerAge and get something as shown below?

- **Action Man:** 'Child' (5%), 'Teenager' (10%), 'Adult' (60%), 'Pensionist' (25%)
- **Matrix:** 'Child' (5%), 'Teenager' (20%), 'Adult' (65%), 'Pensionist' (10%)

Note that I have already tried to include in the data the sorted column CustomerAge and keep it Hidden in the chart, but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

So you basically expect a random sort based on your logic instead of an actual, systemic logic like alphanumeric asc or desc. What you need for that is to create your own sort order column that yields a systematically sortable result. Child = 1, Teenager = 2, Adult = 3, Pensionist = 4. Your attribute members currently just do not make any sense in terms of machine-interpreted sorting whereas a human brain thinks "hey that's a logical progression"

A screenshot of what your issue is would help because with prefixes it works nicely. Both with adding the sort column as hidden and obviously also as displayed one:

[image]

Comment: I have tried to make my CustomerAge to be my sort order column and then hide it from the graphic, as I say in the last line. The thing is the chart loses the asc order on CustomerAge and imposes a desc order on CustomerAgeGroup.

I would be happy if I could change the desc order of CustomerAgeGroup  to an asc order, because like that I could rename the age groups as '1 - Child', '2 - Teenager', etc

Comment: Update and screenshot proof above